# Problems trigger jquery

Tags: jquery

In rails i created an hidden form that should be submitted when the user clicks on an submit button of another form:

```
 <th><%= f.submit :id => 'button1',  :class => 'btn btn-small btn-primary', :onclick => "sketch.toDataURL(); myway()"  %>
```

To make this possible i added an jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function myway() {
   $('#my_form').trigger('submit');
  }
$("#button1").click(function(){
$('#my_form').trigger('submit');
});
```

Somehow i get the error: myway is not defined?

Comment: As your document.ready parenthesis are not close did you get any  error in Firefox console?

Comment: If `my_form` refers to a form element then you can give `$('#my_form').submit()`, why trigger?

Comment: @anu `$('#my_form').submit()` is just a shorthand for `$('#my_form').trigger('submit')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, try that instead, preventing default behaviour on button submit click:

```
function myway() {
    $('#my_form')[0].submit(); //here submit using javascript, not jquery.
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button1").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Now it works to submit the second form. But somehow the first doesnt work. The error: ReferenceError: myway is not defined
[Bei diesem Fehler anhalten]  

sketch.toDataURL(); myway()

Answer (score 0):

Try This;

```
<script>
function myway() {
   $('#my_form').trigger('submit');
}
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $("#button1").click(function(){
  $('#my_form').trigger('submit');
});
</script>
```